# Can I use vector asset in my android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an android app  and plan to publish it in market.I just want to ask that can I use icons provided by android studio in my app?

Is it legal to use? Would I get any copyright infringement case?

Also, I am using SharedPreferences. So what permissions would I need to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, icons provided by Android-Studio are **free to use**. It won't be an issue.

And you **don't need any special permission** to use shared preferences.